# Set the Margin property in C++/CX in a Windows 8 XAML project

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am trying to set the `Margin` of my `Ellipse` through code.  How can I set the `Margin` of  `p`?

```
auto p = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Shapes::Ellipse();
p->Height=100.0;
p->Width=100.0;
//p->Margin="36,19,0,0";
auto t = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Thickness(10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thickness` is a value type, not a reference type, so it is not created with `ref new`.

```
p->Margin = Windows::UI::Xaml::Thickness(10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0);
```